# How to show local time instead of universal time in NGINX HTTP Date parameter

Tags: nginx

How can I configure NGINX to show Local time (CEST) in HTTP Date parameter instead of Universal Time (UTC)?

I have added

```
export TZ="Europe/Ljubljana"
```

to /etc/init.d/nginx and

```
env TZ="Europe/ljubljana";
```

to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Log file (/var/log/nginx/access.log) shows local time, but HTTP response shows universal time (curl --head http://mysite).

For the following time settings

```
Current default time zone: 'Europe/Ljubljana'
Local time is now:      Mon Jun 26 11:23:24 CEST 2017.
Universal Time is now:  Mon Jun 26 09:23:24 UTC 2017.
```

I would like to see HTTP header

```
Date: Mon, 26 Jun 2017 11:23:24 CEST
```

not

```
Date: Mon, 26 Jun 2017 09:23:24 GMT
```

Comment: The date format is defined in RFC 7231 to be UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't affect this header with any configuration. It is standard requirement.

> The Date general-header field represents the date and time at which
>   the message was originated, having the same semantics as orig-date in
>   RFC 822. The field value is an HTTP-date, as described in section
>   3.3.1; it MUST be sent in RFC 1123 [8]-date format.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

> All HTTP date/time stamps MUST be represented in Greenwich Mean Time
>   (GMT), without exception. For the purposes of HTTP, GMT is exactly
>   equal to UTC (Coordinated Universal Time). This is indicated in the
>   first two formats by the inclusion of "GMT" as the three-letter
>   abbreviation for time zone, and MUST be assumed when reading the
>   asctime format. HTTP-date is case sensitive and MUST NOT include
>   additional LWS beyond that specifically included as SP in the grammar.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3.1 and